# How to pass trace id to logger so that request and app logs are grouped together in Google App Engine Standard (Java)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to get my [Request and App logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/writing-application-logs?tab=java) to group together when viewing them in the Google Cloud Console Logs Explorer. I am running Spring Boot app on Google App Engine Standard (Java).

So far, I am able to get the `trace id` from the header of a request to a url endpoint by reading the `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` header. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/trace-log-integration#associating) say I need to pass this `trace id` to the LogEntry object:

> To associate a log entry with a trace by setting the trace field in
> the LogEntry object. The trace field must be set to a string with the
> following format:
>
> projects/PROJECT_ID/traces/TRACE_ID
>
> where PROJECT_ID is your Google
> Cloud project ID and TRACE_ID is the trace identifier

This is where I am not sure what to do next. How do I pass in the `trace id` to my logger? This is the code I use to write logs:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyLogClass.class.getName());
logger.info("my log statement");
```